# Large arrays: so as not to use too much RAM?

Tags: arrays, memory, out-of-memory, bigdata

I created a 3-dimensional array like this:

```
Array_ <- array( NA, a =78000, b =123, c=1000)
```

For each element, a value of 0 or 1 will be allocated according to a condition.

In the 3 loops to fill each dimension of the array.

Assuming that in the loops it is in position Array_[ 1, i, 1] i = 1 : 123.

A random number is generated

```
u <- runif(1, min =0, max=1)
```

and this is compared with a number q from a pre-defined table (qx-M or qx-F) of values ​​less than 1:

```
if u >= q
```

the position Array_[ 1, 1.1] <-1 from there it goes to i=2 and makes the same comparison with a new `u`. If the condition u >= q the position in the array receives value 0 and 0 until the end of the loop of i. The big problem is that in an array of that size the RAM memory runs out. I'm using windows virtual memory and memory.limit() with high value. Clearly there is some optimization I can do and I don't know how to do it.

The code:

```
scenes <-1000

for(y in 1:scenes) { 
  
  for(b in 1:nrow(dadosMBA_Ativos)){ #nrow(dadosMBA_Ativos) = 78000
    p <- 0
    k <- 0
    sex <-dadosMBA_Ativos[b,5]# COLUMN OF SEX
    age <- dadosMBA_Ativos[b,48] # COLUMN OF AGES
    
    if (sex == toupper("M")) {
      
      for (i in 1:(LT-age)) {# LT = 123
        
        u <- runif(1, min=0, max=1)
        
        if (u > qx_M[age + p]) {
          k <- 1
          p <- p + k
          
          if (i > 1 && Array_[b,i-1,y] == 0) {
            
            Array_[b,i,y]<-0
            
          } else {
            Array_[b,i,y]<-1
          }
          
        } else {
          
          k <- 0
          Array_[b,i,y]<-k
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (i in 1:(LT-age)) {
        
        u <- runif(1, min=0, max=1)
        
        if( qx_F[age + p] < u) {
          k <- 1
          p <- p + k

          if(i > 1 && Array_[b,i-1,y]== 0) {
            
            Array_[b,i,y]<-0
            
          } else { 
            Array_[b,i,y]<-1
          }
       } else {
          
          k <- 0
          Array_[b,i,y]<-k
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

So far my PC has done the job and the Array_ is with 76.8 GB. However, some elements of the Array are NA because of the 2nd dimension of the Array. So I tried to run the code

```
Array_ <- replace(x = Array_, list = is.na(Array_), values ​​= 0)
```

and then the computer returned memory allocation error.

Probably partners here will be able to suggest a way to optimize this.

I would like to thank anyone who is willing to help.